# JNLP and Splash Screen

Tags: java, screen, java-web-start, jnlp, splash-screen

Sorry, but my English is not very good.

I am having a issue with JNLP and Splash Screen.

When I launch my app with file .jar, the my Splash Screen start correctly, but when I start my app with file .jnlp the image in Splash Screen don't start.

Someone have any idea from how I can resolve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

thank you for answer, but I still have a doubt.

I think that the code above is for change the splash standard from java, is correct?

I don't want change the splash from java, but the splash from my app that will show while load, below follow my code.

```
try {  
                SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();       
                splash.setImageURL(new URL("Imagens/Splash.png");
                Graphics2D g = splash.createGraphics();  


            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {  

                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {  
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {  
                Logger.getLogger(Splash.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
            }
```